# Pods are shown as TERMINATED after kubernetes node reboot/restart

Tags: kubernetes, nodes, restart, terminate, reboot

We are running a reboot (`sudo systemctl reboot`) of a worker node with Kubernetes version v1.22.4.

We observe that pods on the rebooted node are presented with status TERMINATED.

```
kubectl get pod loggingx-7c879bf5c8-nvxls -n footprint”

NAME                        READY   STATUS       RESTARTS       AGE
loggingx-7c879bf5c8-nvxls   3/3     Terminated   10 (44m ago)   29
```

**Question:**
All containers are up 3/3. Why is the status still **Terminated** ?

```
kubectl describe pod loggingx-7c879bf5c8-nvxls -n footprint”

Name:         loggingx-7c879bf5c8-nvxls
Namespace:    footprint
Priority:     0
Node:         node-10-63-134-154/10.63.134.154
Start Time:   Mon, 08 Aug 2022 07:07:15 +0000
.
.
.
Status:       Running
Reason:       Terminated
Message:      Pod was terminated in response to imminent node shutdown.
```

**Question:**  The status presented from `kubectl get pod` .. and `kubectl describe pod` is different. Why ?

We used the Lens tool and could confirm that the pods are actually running after the reboot!

This behavior applies to both deployments and statefulsets.

We ran the same test in a cluster with kubernetes v1.20.4:
After the reboot is completed, the node becomes ready again and pods are recreated in new/or same worker node.

It looks to us as that the new Beta feature "[Non graceful node shutdown](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/architecture/nodes/#graceful-node-shutdown)"  introduced with v.1.21 has a strange impact on node reboot use case.

Have you had any similar experiences?

BR,
Thomas

Comment: One thing you could try would be to disable graceful shutdown (it's enabled by default) and try running the test again..

Comment: Yes, we tried it and now all the pods came up running when
• shutdownGracePeriod: 0s
• shutdownGracePeriodCriticalPods: 0s